# Does a VPN app help hide my devices Mac address?

Tags: vpn

So whenever I get banned on Facebook now, they ban my other profiles that I made for while I'm banned. This is been happening to me for years now they just continuously ban me over and over again.

So now once I'm banned like I said they ban all my profiles at one time. So I thought about getting a VPN and hopes to hide my IP because I was assuming that's how they were getting me.

But I was informed that it is my MAC address.... so does the VPN not block that out? How do I get around this? Once I got banned this time I tried making a new profile and it wouldn't even allow me to make the new profile lol they hate me that much

Comment: “But I was informed that it is my MAC address....” Facebook and other websites have 100% no idea what your MAC address is. How Facebook identifies people is not 100% clear, but the vast majority of websites out there do machine fingerprinting to ID who you are. [Read up on it here](https://blog.mozilla.org/internetcitizen/2018/07/26/this-is-your-digital-fingerprint/). Essentially the only way to circumvent this is to throw out all of your devices, get new devices and then get a new IP address. But as long as you engage in aberrant behavior online, you will be identified and banned.

Answer (score 0):

With (say) Express VPN, you need to subscribe to their Hide my IP facility.  Natively, no, your IP address is not hidden

https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/hide-my-ip

Just out of curiosity, why not adapt to Facebook's code of conduct?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The user “im phukin right” is most likely not a “she” because the desire of this question seems to be 100% the way a “he” would behave to fake people out.

Comment: @JakeGould Very good point, sir. I haven't thought about that possibility but it makes lots of sense.